# Abyss Beyond Dreams: How did this Faller get here?

Tags: commonwealth-saga

After Svlasta saves the schoolkids from the stampede (becoming the "Hero of Eynsham Square" in doing so), the government recovers the dead body of the Faller that started the stampede. It is later revealed that the Faller had some sort of minuscule fibers inside its brain, something that had never been seen before. Later in the book, after transitioning to Nigel's POV, they deliberately eggsume a criminal they captured. One he is eggsumed, they invade his brain with a direct memory read, which sounds to be similar to the fibers mentioned above. Additionally, the description of the wound on the Faller's hand matches Kysandra shooting his hand and then having it repaired in their pod. Based on these two things, I'm assuming the Faller that caused the stampede is the same one that Nigel captured/interrogated/whatever.

How did that Faller end up at the square though? Did they send it deliberately? Can they control it? Did it escape? What happens to the Faller after they're done with the memory read is never explained, so I haven't figured out if this is Nigel attempting to deliberately cause Svlasta to become a hero (what were they going to do with the random innocent if nobody stopped the Faller?) or if it was coincidental and worked out somehow.

Comment: I think I know the answer to this but I'm probably going to have to read the book again to confirm.. that may take some time. I think Nigel had it planned and had alternatives if things went wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I got the impression it was part of a plan, but most of their plans were explicitly revealed at one point or another, or at least had more "hey hey look at this and this and look how conveniently they fit together" so I wasn't 100% on this being deliberate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the Faller in the Eynsham Square is Proval, the would be rapist that they eggsumed and probed.

This can be see when they first capture him.

> *‘He’s hardly broken. I think two fingers are still intact.*

When they fix him

> *It repaired his hand to a degree, cauterizing the flesh and repairing the two remaining fingers.*

And when they track the Faller at Eynsham Square

> *One hand only had two fingers.*

We can assume that they can control the Faller because as soon as it's shell drops

> *Demitri ’pathed a neuromeme variant to suppress the Faller’s primary thought routines –providing they were close to a human’s. The body relaxed further.*

This suggests that the filaments may not even be needed to control the Fallers, though having a permanent method implanted inside one is probably wise.

Nigel is also too smart to let a Faller escape, he would have killed it, or the Faller would have gotten away from Blair Farm having caused serious collateral damage, which is not evidenced later in.

Nor would Nigel let one roam around uncontrolled and risk all their work.

The Faller would therefore have had to have been placed by Nigel at the square as part of his aim of destabilising the Captains government and getting the Quantambusters.

As the revolution is being steered in no small part by Nigel thanks to his ANAdroid within the revolutions inner circle, the aim very much seems to make Slvasta a hero and a viable opposition to the Captain. It also gave a massive boost to the movement to stop using *neuts*.

As Nigel is controlling the Faller the escape with the teen boy would have been orchestrated to show that this obviously is a Faller. Nigel would have needed the Faller to be caught so that there was no doubt it was Fallers controlling the neuts, a smoking gun so to speak. He was always destined to fail and would never have gotten away with the teen.

As to what would happen if it all went wrong. Nigel, Kysandra and the ANAdroids are all able to manipulate the memory layer of the void. If it all went wrong they could just jump back, and try it a bit differently the next time.